# New line character used in Wikimedia

Tags: formatting, mediawiki, line-breaks, wikimedia, wikitext

What is the newline character used in [Wikimedia projects](http://www.wikimedia.org/) formatting?

Because there is no undo, redo, or easy/fast save mechanism, I wrote a Wikimedia page in a normal text editor. Unfortunately, when I pasted it to my Wikimedia entry, all the new lines are gone.

I have tried using `\n`, `\r`, `\n\r`, `\n\n`, `\r\r`, `\n\r\n\r`, `<br>`, and `<p></p>` as my line breaks. However, none of them work. In the case of my `\n`, `\r` variations, nothing happens. In the case of the html tags, I get line breaks, but none of the other formatting works.

What is going on here? How do I fix this?

*EDIT:* I have also tried `\r\n`.

Addendum: Text recovery now works for me, after upgrading to 1.24.

Comment: Looks like you tried everything but the right one... `\r\n` should be the newline you seek, however I don't know how wikimedia does it.

Comment: If you mean MediaWiki markup, [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Line-break_handling) describes it.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Sorry, tried `\r\n` too but forgot to include it. It didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sob, please don't make newlines manually. If you really need to use a local text editor, save text in UTF-8 encoding, UNIX newlines (`\n`), and use that.

Moving stuff around manually is not ideal either, especially as you will have to guess the markup because you can't have local parsing. It's going to be a pain. Use proper software, i.e. [LibreOffice](http://libreoffice.org/), and [use the wiki-publisher tool](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68080/how-do-i-edit-mediawiki-articles-from-libreoffice-writer) which handles markup conversion automatically (as well as publishing via API if you wish).

P.s.: In all my browsers, undo, redo and text recovery work perfectly in MediaWiki's editor. Try using a modern browser.

Comment: I was using 1.19 at the time, and text recovery didn't work. After upgrading to 1.24, text recovery works.

Comment: @MirroredFate, better so then. I don't remember ever having this problem with Firefox in the last several years, but maybe you experienced an upgrade mismatch between browser and wiki.